# MySQL workbench 6.2 failed to connect to server

Tags: mysql

All,

I am using win 8 machine. i have installed MYSQL workbench 6.2, however, when i try to establish connection, it is failing.

Do i have to have Microsoft Server 2012 installed first to the machine?

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: Is the user you use for that connection granted to for public AND for localhost?

Comment: Do you have any sql server in your machine?

Comment: @lolka_bolka - i have MS SQL Server 2012 (developer edition).

Comment: @cboden - it is for local host and i am connection to standard tcp

Comment: @Begueradj - the error is: "Cannot connect to server 27.0.xx with port 3306.

Comment: ok wait ... you try to connect the MYSQL workbench to a MS SQL Server? And the server is in the internet because of IP 27.0.xx? Are you sure that that server is accessble? Can you establish a ODBC connection to it? You should try that first before starting with the workbench. BTW it don't think that it is really a good idea to do that ... better use the MS SQL Server Management Studio for that.